# How to enable 4G in Samsung Galaxy S4 (SPH-L720)?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, 4g

I have a Samsung Galaxy S4 (SPH-L720). I want to use 4G.

I'm using Zong which has 4G internet and I'm using 4G on my other mobile, but I want to use 4G on this mobile because it has better performance than the other.

How can I enable 4G in Samsung Galaxy S4 (SPH-L720)?

Answer (score 0):

Go in Settings and then Mobile Network. If you want to use only 4G, then change the Network Mode to LTE only, and then just right next to it is the network operator, click that option and go for automatic search and register.

Your cell will be registered to the 4G bands of your career, and then simply turn the Mobile Data on.

Comment: Thanks For Your Reply. I tried this but when I set it to LTE the sim signals shows a red *.

Comment: Then propably your region wont be having 4G coverage brother!